# Unity3d 5.3.1 Won't Start

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just loaded the newest Unity3d 5.3.1 on a windows 7 machine. All prior Unity versions have worked but this one pops up the Unity screen then kills the program. Looked around but don't see anyone with the same issue. Any Ideas?

Comment: You should ask on Unity Answers, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try install Unity 5.3.1p2 patch. 
[PATCH RELEASES](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases)

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I'll do that but I also found unlike other versions, I had to uninstall Unity from the machine and then reinstall it and now it works. The previous versions didn't make me do that.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Have a nice day!

Comment: Kamil, actually you were more right than I was. The removal and install looked like it work but program crashed after login but after I applied the 5.3.1p2 patch everything is great! Thanks Much!